# Issue when trying to use partial view inside view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

still learning MVC (slowly) which I am enjoying but having some trouble with partial views. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

This is the error I am getting:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary
> is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[mvc_project.Models.Contact]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[mvc_project.ViewModels.ViewContactsVM]'.

I created the partial view using the List template.

Chose my model ViewContactsVM

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace mvc_project.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewContactsVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int ContactID { get; set; } 
        public int ClientID { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Contact Name")]
        public string ContactName { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Contact Phone Number")]
        public string ContactPhoneNumber { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Contact Email Address")]
        public string ContactEmailAddress { get; set; } 
        [DisplayName("Job Title")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; } 
        public string AddedBy { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult _ContactList(int id)
        {
            using (var context = new mvc_projectEntities())
            {
                var data = context.Contacts.Where(x => x.ClientID == id).ToList();
                return View(data);
            }
        }
```

_ContactsList Partial View Page:

```
@model IEnumerable<mvc_project.ViewModels.ViewContactsVM>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactPhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactEmailAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitle)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedBy)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactPhoneNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactEmailAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ContactID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ContactID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ContactID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Details View Page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

@Html.Action("_ContactList")
```

Comment: Add definition of the `mvc_project.Models.Contact` to post, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to pass the ViewContactsVM type to the view, as it defined in the view data model. Therefore try:

```cs
public ActionResult _ContactList(int id)
{
    using (var context = new mvc_projectEntities())
    {
        var data = context.Contacts
                    .Where(x => x.ClientID == id)
                    .Select(c => new mvc_project.ViewModels.ViewContactsVM() {
                        ContactID = c.ContactID, 
                        ClientID = c.ClientID, 
                        ContactName = c.ContactName
                        ...
                        })
                    .ToList();
        return View(data);
    }
}
```